# Test "disabled" attribute with bUnit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, bunit

Please see this simplified Blazor component `MyComponent`:

```cs
<button id="enableButton" @onclick="Enable">Enable</button>
<button id="disableButton" @onclick="Disable">Disable</button>

<select disabled="@_disabled">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

@code {
    private bool _disabled;
    private void Enable() { _disabled = false; }
    private void Disable() { _disabled = true; }
}
```

And here are two simple bUnit tests for the Blazor component:

```cs
[Test]
public void Enable()
{
    using var testContext = new TestContext();
    var testee = testContext.RenderComponent<MyComponent>();

    testee.Find("[id^=\"enableButton\"]").Click();

    testee.Find("select").IsDisabled().Should().BeFalse();
}

[Test]
public void Disable()
{
    using var testContext = new TestContext();
    var testee = testContext.RenderComponent<MyComponent>();

    testee.Find("[id^=\"disableButton\"]").Click();

    testee.Find("select").IsDisabled().Should().BeTrue();
}
```

The `Disable` test fails with `Expected testee.Find("select").IsDisabled() to be true, but found False.`. But when rendering `MyComponent` in the browser, everything works as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blazor renders all boolean attributes that are truthy without a value, and when a boolean attribute is assigned false, it is simply not rendered. That is perfectly legal from a HTML5 spec point of view, but non-the-less surprising.

This means that when your `_disabled` is `false`, the `disabled` attribute does not exist in the rendered markup. To verify this, you can do:

```
testee.Find("select").HasAttribute("disabled").Should().BeFalse()
```

When `_disabled` is `true`, you can verify this with:

```cs
testee.Find("select").HasAttribute("disabled").Should().BeTrue();
```